# With React Testing Library, how to wrap component with a specific route?

Tags: react-router, react-testing-library

I've looked at several examples, trying to get my React Testing Library test to simulate a specific URL that my React component will then utilize with `useParams`.

For example, here's one "official" article on the subject: https://react-testing-examples.com/jest-rtl/react-router/

So I tried this code:

```
  function renderDom(component) {
    const companyId = 226;
    const userId = 123;
    // console.log(component, companyId, userId);
    return {
      ...render(
        <SessionProvider>
          <AppProvider>
            <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[`/users/company/${companyId}/user-list/${userId}`]} initialIndex={0}>
              <Route path='/users/company/:companyId/user-list/:userId'>
                {component}
              </Route>
            </MemoryRouter>
          </AppProvider>
        </SessionProvider>
      )
    };
  };
```

But it didn't work.  When I ran the test using this code, my console logs within my component code didn't actually run.

So I'm looking for a proven way to wrap my component such that it simulates a URL.

Comment: The MemoryRouter also needs `initialIndex={1}` as prop to determine which route to mock first.

Comment: @johnnypeter Thank you!  I will try this.

Comment: Following your lead, I did finally get things working.  Two notes:
 1. `initialIndex={0}`
 2. Getting all of the forward slashes precisely correct is critical.

I've updated the code in the question to reflect a working solution!